# Displaying two JSP page output in the single browser page

Tags: jsp

I have 3 JSP pages like 1.jsp,2.jsp and 3.jsp. on submit of  1.jsp, will send form parameters to 2.jsp and 3.jsp.  I want display output of 2.jsp+3.jsp in the single browser.How it is to be done.Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<jsp:include>` directive.

E.g. in your case, in `1.jsp` file, you can include 2.jsp and 3.jsp:

```
<jsp:include page="2.jsp">
<jsp:include page="3.jsp">
```

Further, you need to intercept the form submit event in 1.jsp and display the contents of 2.jsp and 3.jsp with the values from the form on 1.jsp. During the form submit event handler, you can hide the contents of the form on 1.jsp and only display the contents of 2.jsp and 3.jsp.